# HibernateOptimisticLockingFailure exception when cloning table data using Grails ORM

Tags: mysql, grails

In our project, we are "cloning table data" and "subsequent tables" in the hierarchy. For this, in the domain objects, we are writing a "clone()" method, creating an object of the class and then setting the properties in the created object. What we are doing in code is like this (this is the clone object of a "dummy Book.groovy class" representing book table in database)

```
public Book clone(def newParent) {
    def clonedBook = new Book(properties)
    clonedBook.parent=newParent
    clonedBook.<childObject>=<childObject>*.clone(clonedBook)
    return clonedBook
}
```

The "clone()" method of Book is called from the clone method of the domain class of parent table, and it in turn calls "clone()" method of child domain class. In database the foreign keys are made as ON DELETE NO ACTION

So while running this way, I was getting integrity constraint violation exception, which got resolved by changing the foreign keys from "ON DELETE NO ACTION to ON DELETE CASCADE". Then I started getting "HibernateOptimisticLockingFailure exception". This was also solved by not passing 'properties' in constructor of "clonedBook", but setting the properties of Book.groovy explicitly in "clonedBook". Example, the "clone()" method is

```
public Book clone(def newParent) {
    def clonedBook = new Book()    //properties not passed here
    clonedBook.name = name   //explicitly set
    clonedBook.price = price  //explicitly set
    ...
}
```

But I was unable to find why the problem was solved this way, or what was wrong the previous way. I am using "Grails 2.4.4" and MySQL database